# setTimeout не работатет должным образом

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Всем привет.
Данно: на странице есть inpit="search" c id="search" и input="submit" с id="submit".
Необходимо: ввести текст в поле поиска и нажать кнопку submit. И только через три секунды должен появиться alert с текстом, который я ввел в поиск. onclick использовать только в js коде.
Реализовал код следующим образом, но ничего не работает.

```
        submit.onclick=function(){
        setTimeout(function func() {
        if ((document.getElementById("search").value == "hi")) {
            return alert(" there")
        } else {
            return alert(document.getElementById("search").value)
        }
    } ,3000)
    }
```

Comment: Вроде должно работать. Сниппет сделай.

Answer (score 0):

Мне почему-то кажется что автор хотел сделать задержку, если это не так, то это моя вина.

```js
let isSubmit = false;

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 
 if (isSubmit) return;
 
 isSubmit = true;
 setTimeout(() => isSubmit = false, 3000);
 
 const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target).entries());

 if (data.text === "hi")
  return alert('Hello !');
  
 alert(data.text);
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" name="text">
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```